# Questions about metric tensor

Tags: metric-tensor, definition, notation

Why $$g_{ik}g^{kl}=\delta ^l_i~?$$ That is why the two quantities on LHS are reciprocal tensor to each other? Is this a definition? Or it can be proved in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would define $g^{\mu\nu}$ with the reciprocal basis and then follow the identity between $g^{\mu\nu}$ and $g_{\mu\nu}$ from the definition of the reciprocal basis. We define the metric tensor as the scalar product of the basis vectors $\{\mathbf{e}_\mu\}$: 
$$g_{\mu\nu}\equiv \mathbf{e}_\mu \cdot \mathbf{e}_\nu$$

and the metric $g^{\mu\nu}$ with the reciprocal basis $\{\mathbf{e}^\mu\}$:$$g^{\mu\nu}\equiv \mathbf{e}^\mu \cdot \mathbf{e}^\nu.$$

The defining property of the reciprocal basis $\{\mathbf{e}^\nu\}$ is $$\mathbf{e}_\mu\cdot\mathbf{e}^\nu\equiv\delta_\mu^{~~\nu}.$$

If one defines them like this then $g_{\mu\alpha}g^{\alpha\nu}=\delta_\mu^{~~\nu}$ is a consequence of the orthogonality of $\{\mathbf{e}^\mu\}$ and $\{\mathbf{e}_\mu\}$:

\begin{align}
g_{\mu\alpha}g^{\alpha\nu}&=\mathbf{e}_\mu \cdot (\mathbf{e}_\alpha\cdot\mathbf{e}^\alpha) \cdot \mathbf{e}^\nu\\
&=\mathbf{e}_\mu \cdot (1) \cdot \mathbf{e}^\nu\\
&=\mathbf{e}_\mu \cdot \mathbf{e}^\nu\\
&=\delta_\mu^{~~\nu}.\\
\end{align}

Therefore we can call the metric of the reciprocal basis the inverse metric of the "normal" basis. $g_{\mu\alpha}g^{\alpha\nu}=\delta_\mu^{~~\nu}$ now reads $(\underline{g})(\underline{g})^{-1}=\underline{1}$ in matrix notation.

Going over the two basis since the properties of the metric follow from the basis vectors and their relations is the proper way I think.